# Apache Tomcat Startup WARNING (ExceptionInInitializerError)

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, eclipse-wtp, documentum, documentum6.5

I have an error starting webtop 6.5 sp3 in eclipse with tomcat. DFC jars are added to classpath and buildpath already. Accessing the webapplication goes to a blank page

Any ideas on how to resolve this?

```
Warning: WDK application could not be started, error msg= null, error type=java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError. This message can be ignored during the installation.
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.documentum.fc.client.DfClient.<clinit>(DfClient.java:700)
    at com.documentum.com.DfClientX.getLocalClient(DfClientX.java:43)
    at com.documentum.web.env.NotificationManager.contextInitialized(NotificationManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:3795)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4252)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1014)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:736)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1014)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:448)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:700)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:552)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:295)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:433)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.documentum.fc.impl.security.action.GetResourceAsStreamAction.run(GetResourceAsStreamAction.java:19)
    at com.documentum.fc.impl.security.action.GetResourceAsStreamAction.run(GetResourceAsStreamAction.java:9)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.bof.cache.CacheManifest$CacheSchemaEntityResolver.resolveEntity(CacheManifest.java:1040)
    at com.documentum.xerces_2_8_0.xerces.util.EntityResolverWrapper.resolveEntity(Unknown Source)
    at com.documentum.xerces_2_8_0.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager.resolveEntity(Unknown Source)
    at com.documentum.xerces_2_8_0.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.resolveDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.documentum.xerces_2_8_0.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.findSchemaGrammar(Unknown Source)
    at com.documentum.xerces_2_8_0.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.documentum.xerces_2_8_0.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.documentum.xerces_2_8_0.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.documentum.xerces_2_8_0.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDispatcher.scanRootElementHook(Unknown Source)
    at com.documentum.xerces_2_8_0.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at com.documentum.xerces_2_8_0.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.documentum.xerces_2_8_0.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.documentum.xerces_2_8_0.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.documentum.xerces_2_8_0.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.documentum.xerces_2_8_0.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.documentum.xml.jaxp.DfDocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DfDocumentBuilderImpl.java:189)
    at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.bof.cache.CacheManifest.syncDocumentAndAcquireLockIfNeeded(CacheManifest.java:591)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.bof.cache.CacheManifest.getVersionMasterStamp(CacheManifest.java:309)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.bof.cache.DefaultLocalAccessor.getMasterStamp(DefaultLocalAccessor.java:118)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.bof.cache.DocbaseClassCache.getMasterStamp(DocbaseClassCache.java:48)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.bof.cache.ClassCacheManager.getMasterStamp(ClassCacheManager.java:323)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.bof.cache.BofConsistencyChecker.init(BofConsistencyChecker.java:24)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.bof.cache.ClassCacheManager.initDocbase(ClassCacheManager.java:548)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.bof.cache.ClassCacheManager.initialDiscovery(ClassCacheManager.java:530)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.bof.cache.ClassCacheManager.<init>(ClassCacheManager.java:394)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.bof.cache.ClassCacheManager.getInstance(ClassCacheManager.java:48)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.bof.classmgmt.ModuleManager.init(ModuleManager.java:291)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.impl.bof.classmgmt.ModuleManager.getInstance(ModuleManager.java:36)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.security.impl.DfcIdentityPublisher.<init>(DfcIdentityPublisher.java:44)
    at com.documentum.fc.client.security.internal.RegistrationMgr.register(RegistrationMgr.java:34)
    at com.documentum.fc.impl.RuntimeContext.<clinit>(RuntimeContext.java:191)
    ... 18 more
28 juil. 2011 14:07:41 org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol start
```

Comment: This is a Warning and not an Error. Is it preventing your server from loading?

Comment: Looks like the sever loads but accessing the webapp shows a blank page. (Editing the question with this info)

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess, but it looks to me like you are missing a config file. Do you have the config directory in your classpath?

Comment: It's a good guess. I have added the config folder the the build path, the CLASSPATH variable in windows, to the classpath in the server launch configuration, perhaps it needs to be added somewhere else. I know this config folder is famous for giving errors

Comment: Back in the 5.2.5 days we added it to the Tomcat classpath. I assume that is what you mean by server launch configuration. Given that the failure is occurring during DfClient class initialisation I would think that it is the main Documentum config file that is missing which implies that the classpath is stil not correct for Tomcat. You should be able to use the shared.loader property in catalina.properties to add the required Documentum (dctm.jar, config etc) classpath entries